# facebook share button not displaying content

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph, meta

Alright so I have set my meta tags exactly how it says on the facebook developer page, and the scraper even shows the data that will be showed to be correct, but when using the facebook share button on my website http://www.etdigitaldesign.com/, all that it shares is the website url, it doesn't include any of the information from the meta tags, that the scraper says it should. No site name, no description, no image. just the website URL.

This is really confusing to me because the scraper says the share button should be showing the proper info, and I'm using a copy/pasted code snippet from the fb developers page, so I can't see what my error could possibly be...

here is what the scraper shows:image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UiiS.png since I can't post images yet.

and here's my meta code:

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.etdigitaldesign.com" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="ET Digital Design" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="Currently doing a grand opening special, making several free websites to get my name out there. Visit the site if you are interested!" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.etdigitaldesign.com/images/etlogobig.png" />
```

Comment: Looks fine for me, so probably just a local caching issue.

Comment: are you viewing on a mobile? My friend said from mobile devices theres a bar at the very top with a share button, and it works properly -- oddly that's something I didn't even intentionally put in there.....but when i use the share button that's under the like button (the only one viewable from a PC) the window pops up and only shows my url, no description or image. It will share the website and all, but only the url.

How would I even go about fixing a local cache issue? I thought the facebook debugger/scraper tool was supposed to 'reset' your cache?

Comment: I just used the “see this in share dialog” option from the debug tool – it shows up fine in there, and also fine in the final post on my timeline. // By local cache issue, I meant caching on your machine. I think Facebook doesn’t always request fresh data when you call the share dialog, but might be using older data for the preview. And if your OG meta tags weren’t in order when you tried before, or loading timed out or something, it might be that you still get to see the URL only in share dialog for a while.

Comment: The whole reason I even noticed this issue was because I asked on my timeline for my friends to share it, and one of them said it gave them a security issue when they used the share button, and it wouldn't let them....so I tried and the share button only shows the url address, no content or picture. Just tried on my mobile as well, and got the same problem.

This is why I have no idea how to fix it, the scraper shows that it should be sharing the info just fine, this is so confusing lol, its obviously not just local cache because It doesn't work from any of my mobile devices either.

Comment: I also just registered as a Facebook developer, to get an app ID, and I added

    
       <meta property="fb:app_id"        content="MY_APP_ID" />

removed my app id from this post incase it's sensitive info, but it's in there on the page.

Comment: Tried with your URL here and it worked correctly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator

Comment: As I keep saying it looks fine on the scraper, and every other resource, but when you try to share it directly from the page is when it messes up. Due to the lack of answers I found here I just decided to remove the share button from my site. I'll attempt to add it separately and maybe it will work that way.

Answer (score 0):

All [facebook's examples](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.rottentomatoes.com%2Fm%2Fmatrix%2F) have self-closing meta tags, so try that and then re-scrape, if that still doesn't work add a fake parameter eg http://example.com/?20 and scape

At the moment the title and image are showing, just not the description. It shows HHTP status 206,which is partial content, but that's not a problem

Comment: I was using the facebook exampls to begin with......I tried so many things to get it to work, and it's odd that when I share the link to my site on facebook it shows the proper meta info, its only the share button directly on the site that wasn't functioning properly. I decided to just nix the share button and just use the like button. later on I will try to add a third party share button because the facebook official examples are the ones that are giving me the problem